# Configure Play framework messages to not format numbers

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

In the Play Framework, you can define files that have a key=value list of text.

For instance

```
myerror.number=The number {0} is not a double
```

Which I can then get using: `Messages.get("myerror.number", 5);`

And it will say:

> The number 5 is not a double

When going above 1000 though, the output will format it with a group separator, like this: "1,000"

How can I correct the settings to not do this? No separators at all for whole numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N) Play uses the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class for formatting and it generates its output based on the provided [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object. Hence, the thousand separator is used in your example.

The simplest solution is to pass the string value instead the number.

```
Messages.get("myerror.number", String.valueOf(5));
```

Play doesn't provide any global configuration for that purpose.

Comment: Well, too bad. Thanks for the advice.